# Understanding the behaviour of system.time()

Tags: r

I think I must be misunderstanding something about R's system.time() function. If I have the following code in a test.r:

```
for(i in 1:10)
{
    print(system.time(testFunction()))
}
```

(where testFunction() is defined elsewhere, but contains some fairly computationally-intensive code), and run the code, but kill the job after the 1st loop, then receive the following output:

```
> source("test.r")
user  system elapsed
280.388   2.622 288.155
Timing stopped at: 210.891 0.367 211.637
```

why is the value for 'Timing Stopped' less than the elapsed time for the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The timing restarts during the second loop, and since you killed it part way through, it will be less than what you timed for the full first loop.

Comment: Thanks - that makes sense.  I am still confused by the difference between 'user', 'system' and 'elapsed' times given in ?proc.time - why is 'elapsed' not the sum of the other 2 values?

Comment: It sounds like they should, but generally they do not. Here is a good R-help post about this topic that includes an example: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2008-April/160611.html

Comment: The example is better than the general R help file ones, but it still doesn't explain why the 2 CPU times are different (and, in the example, one of them is 0.00); will the elapsed time always be orders of magnitude larger than the system time? Under what circumstances will `user` and `elapsed` be similar (as in my example), or be very different (as in the example on the R-help post)?